# Vector bundle $(E,M)$ of rank $0$: sections of $E$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Am I right that a vector bundle $(E,M)$ of rank 0 means that sections of $E$ are functions $f:M \to M$?

Comment: Why do you think you are right?  Have you tried to prove it?

Comment: @JasonDeVito Well, rank 0 means $E$ and $M$ are diffeomorphic. So a section of $E$ is a map from $M$ to $E \equiv M$.

Comment: A vector bundle comes equipped with a map from $E(\cong M)$ to $M$.  Sections have to respect this map somehow.  How does that enter in?

Comment: A section of $E$ is a map from $M$ to $E$ that ......

Comment: Sorry I don't get how I can use that $\Pi \circ S = id_M $ for a section $S$. All I know is that $S\circ d:M \to M$ where $d$ is the said diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E$ is a rank $0$ vector bundle over $M$, identify $E \cong M\times\{0\}$.  The projection map $\pi:E\to M$ is projection onto the first factor of the product.  Every section of $E$ is a map $s:M\to E$ such that $\pi\circ s = id_M$.

With these three facts, you can *completely* characterize every *single* section of $E$ by asking what sort of function $M\to M\times\{0\}$ composed with projection to $M$ gives the identity on $M$.

Comment: Why did you identify $E$ with $M \times \{0\}$. What's the use of the tag 0?

Comment: The empty basis is a global trivialization of $E$, so we can identify $E$ with the product bundle $M\times\{0\}$.